# Как показать кнопку по нажатии на другую кнопку?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на RadioButton рядом стоящая кнопка стала видна (я ее поставил невидимую). Желательно, через структуру If... Then... Else.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Visible := RadioButton1.Checked;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

вешаешь обработчик события onClick на  RadioButton  - в нем и изменяешь свойство видимости кнопки